# Uniform random sampling of CIELUV for RGB colors

Tags: rgb, color-space, cieluv

Selecting a random color on a computer is a touch harder than I thought it would be.

The naive way of uniform random sampling of 0..255 for R,G,B will tend to draw lots of similar greens. It would make sense to sample from a perceptually uniform space like CIELUV.

A simple way to do this is to sample L,u,v on a regular mesh and ensure the color solid is contained in the bounds (I've seen different bounds for this). If the sample falls outside embedded RGB solid (tested by mapping it XYZ then RGB), reject it and sample again. You can settle for a kludgy-but-guaranteed-to-terminate "bailout" selection (like the naive procedure) if you reject more then some arbitrary threshold number of times.

Testing if the sample lies within RGB needs to be sure to test for the special case of black (some implementations end up being silent on the divide by zero), I believe. If L=0 and either u!=0 or v!=0, then the sample needs to be rejected or else you would end up oversampling the L=0 plane in Luv space.

Does this procedure have an obvious flaw? It seems to work but I did notice that I was rolling black more often than I thought made sense until I thought about what was happening in that case. Can anyone point me to the right bounds on the CIELUV grid to ensure that I am enclosing the RGB solid?

A useful reference for those who don't know it:
https://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php

Answer (score 2):

The key problem with this is that you need bounds to reject samples that fall outside of RGB. I was able to find it worked out here (nice demo on page, API provides convenient functions):
https://www.hsluv.org/

A few things I noticed with uniform sampling of CIELUV in RGB:

- most colors are green and purple (this is true independent of RGB bounds)
- you have a hard time sampling what we think of as yellow (very small volume of high lightness, high chroma space)

I implemented various strategies that focus on sampling *hues* (which is really what we want when we think of "sampling colors") by weighting according to the maximum chromas at that lightness. This makes colors like chromatic light yellows easier to catch and avoids oversampling greens and purples. You can see these methods in actions here (select "randomize colors"):

https://www.mysticsymbolic.art/

Source for color randomizers here:
https://github.com/mittimithai/mystic-symbolic/blob/chromacorners/lib/random-colors.ts

Comment: Yes, my answer was mainly solving for your stated problem of too many black. That said, the last part of the answer was using polar coordinates for a random sampling of hue, as opposed to randomizing the uv axes. Good idea to use the hsluv library for bounds. Nevertheless, LUV is not really perceptually uniform, the MacAdam ellipses are still not circles on the UCS plot, so things like yellows are a bit under represented... not to mention that RGB forms a triangle on the chromaticity plot and leaves out a substantial portion of the visible gamut.

Comment: So then to continue that line of thought, a look-up table with interpolation could allow the adjustment of randomized hue values to a more uniform distribution — though it's useful to note that our human perception of hue is not a uniform distribution per wavelength — we have much greater discernment in hue around blue, and much less around green, but more luminance discernment in green. So a question is do you want a uniform random distribution of hue based on wavelength or based on perception?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while you don't show the code you are using to generate the random numbers and then apply them to the CIELUV color space, I'm going to guess that you are creating a random number 0.0-100.0 from a random number generator, and then just assigning it to **L<sup>*</sup>**.

***That will most likely give you a lot of black or very dark results.***

### Let Me Explain

**L<sup>*</sup>** of **L <sup>*</sup> u <sup>*</sup> v<sup>*</sup>** is not linear as to light. **Y** of CIEXYZ is linear as to light. **L<sup>*</sup>** is perceptual lightness, so an exponential curve is applied to **Y** to make it *linear to perception* but then non-linear as to light.

#### *TRY THIS*

To get **L<sup>*</sup>** with a random value 0—100:

- Generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0
- Then apply an exponent of 0.42
- Then multiply by 100 to get **L<sup>*</sup>**

```
    Lstar = Math.pow(Math.random(), 0.42) * 100;
```

This takes your random number that represents light, and applies a powercurve that emulates human lightness perception.

#### UV Color

As for the **u** and **v** values, you can probably just leave them as linear random numbers. Constrain **u** to about -84 and +176, and **v** to about -132.5 and +107.5

```
    Urnd = (Math.random() - 0.5521) * 240;
    Vrnd = (Math.random() - 0.3231) * 260;
```

### Polar Color

It might be interesting converting uv to LCh<sub>LUV</sub> or Lsh<sub>LUV</sub>

For **hue**, it's probably as simple as `H = Math.random() * 360`
For **chroma** contrained 0—178: `C = Math.random() * 178`

The next question is, should you find chroma? Or saturation? CIELUV can provide either Hue or Sat — but for directly generating random colors, it seems that chroma is a bit better.

And of course these simple examples are not preventing over-runs, so they color values to be tested to see if they are legal sRGB or not. There's a few things that can be done to constrain the generated values to legal colors, but the object here was to get you to a better distribution without excess black/dark results.

Please let me know of any questions.

Comment: the problem with this is that you need to deal with bounds, without that you can't tell if your color is inside RGB or even in XYZ. Also L* is fine to sample from since it is perceptually uniform. See my answer below.

Comment: @mittimithai also to add, L* is not entirely perceptually uniform, particularly not on a self illuminated display. But the point of my answer above is that a linear random number is not L* — to make a linear random number L*, it needs the lin->L* conversion. The short, down and dirty way is to apply a 0.42 exponent as I indicated, though there are other equations with greater accuracy. You might want to look into sending random values into CIECAM02...

Comment: "so long as the random selection is normally distributed" I believe you mean uniformly distributed, no?
Ofc, nothing is perfectly perceptually uniform but is generally considered the "least wrong": https://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/color7.html#CIELUV
I can't make any guarantee about the display device, but I believe L* is (at least nominally) perceptually uniform.  See how toLinear and fromLinear are used here: https://github.com/hsluv/hsluv/blob/master/haxe/src/hsluv/Hsluv.hx

Comment: @mittimithai  uniform is essentially what I meant.

Comment: @mittimithai As for the other: Bruce MacEvoy's site is awesome. But in context he was discussing the 1976 UCS (the 1976 uʹvʹ chromaticity diagram) as "least wrong," not CIELUV. That said, I do like CIELUV for monitor colors. If you scroll down farther on Bruce's site, you'll see he discusses CIECAM02. And today we also have CIECAM16 (in development) and there are far improved UCS plots that come out of CIECAM02, though CIECAM02 is harder to implement to be sure.

Comment: @mittimithai The toLinear/fromLinear you mention has nothing to do with LUV. Those are the standard TRC decoding/encoding for sRGB to/from linear....... **`L*`** is perceptually uniform-ish for reflected colors as used in CIELAB, for an observer that is adapted to that environment. **`L*`** was "borrowed" for CIELUV, but as part of the research I am doing regarding displays and human perception of contrast, we've found that **`L*`** does not line up well with perception of self-illuminated displays for a variety of reasons. **J** (and **Q**) of CIECAM02 are better predictors.

Comment: @mittimithai But to touch on that last point: **`L*`** assumes viewing reflected colors, and that the white is a perfect reflector, and that the observer is adapted to an environment that is evenly illuminated, and that white is 100. This is not the case for most displays, as the max white is usually set much higher than would be the case for a perfect reflector in the typical environment where the display device is being viewed, example, a "spec" ambient illumination reflected off a white card at 20.